# What does it mean by '-moz-transform' depricated?

Tags: css

I have used the CSS below to make speech bubble for my website, [Yep Website](http://bridale-architectural-antiques.co.uk/yep_3)

It looks okay in google chrome and safari. It does not show up in firefox giving me,  '-moz-transform' depricated? I am not good in designing. I want to seek help how to correct this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
/*SPEECH BUBBLES*/
    .wiget_bottom_all li h3 {
        position:relative;
        padding:15px;
        margin:1em 0 3em;
        color:#fff;
        background:#00B9B7;
        /* css3 */
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f04349), to(#c81e2b));
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(#f04349, #c81e2b);
        background:-o-linear-gradient(#f04349, #c81e2b);
        background:linear-gradient(#00B9B7, #00B9B7);
        -webkit-border-radius:10px;
        -moz-border-radius:10px;
        border-radius:10px;
    }


    /* THE TRIANGLE
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    /* creates the wider right-angled triangle */
    .wiget_bottom_all li h3:before {
        content:"";
        position:absolute;
        bottom:-20px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
        left:105px; /* controls horizontal position */
        border:0;
        border-right-width:30px; /* vary this value to change the angle of the vertex */
        border-bottom-width:20px; /* vary this value to change the height of the triangle. must be equal to the corresponding value in :after */
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:transparent #00B9B7;
        /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
        display:block; 
        width:0;
    }
```

Comment: Its working just fin in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have issues with cross browser codes. You can refer to css tricks for cross browser compatible codes. [Perhaps, read this.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/07/the-principles-of-cross-browser-css-coding/)

Comment: Does not answer the question – this is a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox has probably stopped to support the vendor prefixed css rule.
Do you have a not vendored prefixed css rule: `transform: ...` that will probably do the trick.

According to http://caniuse.com/#search=transform the not vendored prefixed transform rule has been supported in firefox since firefox 19.

edit: You do not use -moz-transform in your example code on s.t. you probably use it somewhere else in your css otherwise the error message really should not be there

Comment: MDN documentation says that non-prefixed `transform` is supported since Firefox 16: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform